# Написать программу для вычисления приближенного значения cos(x)

Tags: javascript

[image: Само задание]

Вот такую формулу вывел

[image: формула]

Написал код, но считается кажется вообще не так... Объясните пожалуйста задание

```
let x = prompt("введите х", '')
let N = prompt("введите N", '')


function factorial(c) {
  return (c != 1) ? c * factorial(c - 1) : 1;
};

let fac = factorial;

        function asd(N, x){
          let k = (N+1)*N
          let sum = 1 + ((Math.pow(-1, N)* Math.pow(x, k)/fac(2*N)));
          alert(sum)

        }

console.log(asd(5, 10))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такие вопросы каждый день появляются.
Ключевые моменты:

Вычисления нужно прервать по заданном условию (модуль слагаемого стал меньше заданной величины)

Очередное слагаемое нетрудно получить из текущего домножением без явного использования степеней и факториалов (в данном случае изменить знак, умножить на икс квадрат, разделить на `k*(k+1)` для получения в знаменателе `k!=(2i)!`)

Псевдокод:

```
y = 1
summ = 0 
k = 1 
while abs(y) > q:
   summ += y
   y = -y * x * x / (k * k + k)
   k += 2
```